# Retaining Twitter Authentication between login sessions

Tags: php, session, twitter

I just wanted to make sure I had this understood correctly.

When I authenticate a Twitter account, I am given back the `access_key` and `access_secret`.

If I want to permanently retain this user's Twitter account authentication between logins, do I store the `access_key` and `access_secret` in the database with the user's account info, and then load those 2 tokens into the session whenever this user logs back in for API access without authenticating with Twitter services upon each login?

Thanks guys

Comment: Yes, that is what you're supposed to do. Although I think its the access key/token is what needs to be stored in the db and the api key is the same throughout

Comment: @Alley, yep, I think that's what I said thought didn't I? The access_key and access_secret would be stored with the user row. API tokens stored in site config

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like that'd be a yes. I ended up finding a helpful article

http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/how-to-authenticate-users-with-twitter-oauth/